# Nested loops Using continue pattern programs

Tags: c

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++)

    {

        for(j=1;j<=2;j++)

        {

            if(i==j)

            {

                continue;

            }         

            printf(“\n%d %d”,i,j);

        }

    }

}
```

This is a nested loop program using continue statement
Please explain Logic behind this code. ..

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand?

Comment: Please read (https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) to better understand how to ask a question on stackoverflow

Comment: The `continue` keyword causes control to pass to the next iteration of the loop, skipping anything else in the loop (in your case, the `printf`)

Answer (score 1):

I hope adding the comments here will make it more explicit.
I will also rearrange the code so it looks a bit better.

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            // When i equals to j, do nothing in the inner loop.
            // i.e. jumps to the second line again.
            continue;
        }
        // Otherwise (i != j) print the value of i and j.
        printf(“\n%d %d”,i,j);
    }
}
```

The use of `continue` here may not be necessary and the above code is equivalent to

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
            // print the value of i and j.
            printf(“\n%d %d”,i,j);
        }
    }
}
```